# Example of composition of Relations

Tags: function-and-relation-composition

Question:
Let the set $A$ be defined as $A = \{ a, b, c, d \}$, and let the relations $R$ and $S$ on the set $A$ be defined as

$R = \{(d, a), (a, b), (b, c)\}$, and $S = \{(a, a), (b, d), (d, c)\}$.

Explain why the ordered pair $(a, b)$ is or is not an element of the composition of $S$ and $R$ (denoted $R \circ S$).

I would think $(a,b)$ is not in composition $R\circ S$ because there does not exist an element $x$ of $A$ such that $aSx$ and $xRa$.

Is my thinking correct? How else would you elaborate that it is or is not in composition $R\circ S$?

Answer (score 2):

If $(a,b)$ is in $R\circ S$, then there is an $x\in A$, such that $aSx$ and $xRb$ (check if you have a typo in the last bit).

But there is such an $x$. I can take $x=a$. I have that $aSa$, and that $aRb$. Hence $a(R\circ S)b$.

Answer (score 1):

You may think on $R\circ S$ as the relation "first $S$, then $R$". Now, $S$ sends $a$ to $a$ and $R$ sends $a$ to $b$. You can conclude the result now?

Answer (score 0):

Think of $S$ as

[image: S]

and of $R$ as

[image: R]

Then the two put together look like

[image: SR]

You may think of a relation in general as a diagram where you put an arrow between two related elements.

---

You have that two elements $x$ and $y$ are related by $R\circ S$ if you have a path between $x$ and $y$ composed of a red arrow and then a blue arrow. (Or more generally, of an arrow of $S$ followed by an arrow of $R$.)

In this case $a$ and $b$ are related because of this path:

[image: ab]

You may also notice with this that in general the composition $R\circ S$ looks like

[image: composition]